# R- Isolating groups in a grouped bar chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to use `ggplot2` to make a bar plot/chart with State initials as the x-axis and nominal and real per-capita personal income (PI) as y-axis value, with the states sorted in ascending order of nominal per-capita PI. I would like for most of the states to have light blue bars for nominal PI and navy bars for Real PI, but would like to highlight states in the Rocky Mountain region with a different color scheme, such as light red and red. I want all of the data to be on the graph, but with states in the Rocky Mountain region to have a different color scheme while appearing in their proper order, similar to this image.

[image]

Here is an example of the data:

```
        GeoName  PI     Real.P   Region
          1 MS  34431   36436   Southeast
          2 WV  36132   37298   Southeast
          3 SC  36677   37199   Southeast
          4 ID  36734   36096   Rocky Mountain
          5 NM  37091   35817   Southwest
          6 KY  37396   38684   Southeast
          7 AL  37512   39216   Southeast
          8 UT  37664   35639   Rocky Mountain
          9 AR  37782   39630   Southeast
          10 AZ 37895   36074   Southwest
          11 GA 38980   38869   Southeast
          12 NC 39171   39184   Southeast
```

I made GeoName into a factor variable where the underlying value is it's rank in the sorted pi nominal PI. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try plotting all the data, then adding a new `geom_bar` with the subset of data  & new colour aesthetics

Comment: Or you could create a new factor, RockyMt == TRUE, for the Rocky Mountain states, and set fill = to that factor.  With scale_fill_manual you can pick the color combinations.